# Github: how to restrict commits on a public repository

Tags: github, privileges

Is there a way to restrict users from making commits to a public repository? I may understand incorrectly, but private repos are not free, and also for private, users cannot access the repo unless invited as a collaborator. I would like GH users to still access the repo, but not able to push commits to it.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Thanks I looked at the link. It it still not clear to me because I used the clone url on the repo page and was able to clone and push to the master branch on the repo without even setting config user.name and user.email, which in my opinion seems like anyone else can do this as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17442930/1144203

Comment: " If you can push to your own repo, it's because you are using one of the supported authentification methods (HTTPS, SSH, ...)" Is that to say that GH users get another clone url?

Comment: Other users use the same clone URLs as the owner. Keep in mind that it doesn't matter if it is [HTTPS](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git)  or [SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys), others will not be able to commit to your public repos unless they are authenticated.

Comment: Thanks. I have a follow up question on how the authentication and key business works, but that goes out of this question's context. I understand now only owners and collaborators can make commits. Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice a difference in read only git:// in the clone url as opposed to the read and write access way with git@. When I tried to push to another's repo using https (which has both read and write access), I got a 403 error (authentication error). The message included my GH username, which made me curious as to how GH knew that. Turns out they have a copy of the computer key that is initiating a push. So finally, only owners and collaborators can push to a repo. I was able to push to my own repo with the https because of my key.

[git github cannot push to origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101203/git-github-cannot-push-to-origin?rq=1)
[How does GitHub handle push security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625522/how-does-github-handle-push-security)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Branch protection rule. it will restrict commits up to an extent. It is under Settings --> Branch